# Arrow Keys don't work with Intellisense in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-2017

I've installed Visual Studio 2017.

If I write some code, the Intellisense window appears:

[image]

In this state anyway the arrow keys don't select the next/previous item in the intellisense list, but they move the cursor to next or previous line, and the intellisense window disappears.

Where can I set the key bindings so I can navigate intellisense with arrow keys?

EDIT:

It seems to be related to VsVim Extension. If I'm in insert mode I've this problem, if I exit insert mode then this starts to work. In VsVim Options I've not found anything related to arrow keys anyway.

Comment: Just file a bug with the extension author.

Comment: I ran into what I think is the same situation, except that I'm not using VsVim and writing C++ instead of XML. I just tried toggling insert mode off and on again and it fixed it. Seems like a bug in the vs2017 editor.

Comment: I'll give it a try thanks.